# How to Send Loop value to another page?

Tags: php, foreach, get

I try to send loop variable to another page with url and GET. but $_GET just only print the last value.

This My code now

```
 ...
 //example
 $codereg[0] = 6;
 $codereg[1] = 2;
 $codereg[2] = 67;

if ($option =='sent')
{

   foreach($codereg as $ids) 
   {
   header("location:checkout.php?id=$userId&productIds[]=$ids");
   }

}
```

and this my checkout.php

```
 <?php
 $userId= $_GET['id'];
 $code= $_GET['productIds'];

 foreach($code as $test)
 {
 echo $test;
 }
 ?>
```

some one help me fix my code or give better solution...

Comment: Miss use of header..., use links to click and go is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($codereg as $ids) 
{
    header("location:checkout.php?id=$userId&productIds[]=$ids");
}
```

You should have only one header location. It can not be in loop.

You can do like this using delimiter comma:

```
header("location:checkout.php?id=$userId&productIds=".implode(',', $ids));
```

And your handler `checkout.php`:

```
$userId= $_GET['id'];
$ids = explode(',', $_GET['productIds']);
var_dump($ids);
```

---

Use `$_GET` is not a good idea for products checkout. `$_GET` can be easy modified and length of url is limited. So count productIds is limited.

You can use `$_SESSION` instead  of `$_GET` to store productIds.

```
$_SESSION["productIds"] = $ids;
```

Comment: what if there are 100 id's ? Implode is a bad option for that. On URL you can pass that much characters. I hope you know that very well

Comment: @Ms.Nehal if there many ids, author should use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_GET`. I only suggested one option how to avoid loop and pass several ids. And yes, `$_SESSION` will be better for checkout.php.

Comment: that is what I'm trying to say. Mention all the options in your answer. Else user's can downvote your answer for a bad option.

Comment: @Ms.Nehal thanks for advice.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
$codereg[0] = 6;
$codereg[1] = 2;
$codereg[2] = 67;

if ($option =='sent') {
   header('location:checkout.php?id=$userId&productIds[]=' . implode('&productIds[]=', $codereg));
}
```